# Calculator to compare mixed portfolio returns

Tags: investing, rate-of-return

I've had my IRA in Betterment for the past 2.5 yrs.  Betterment invests in low fee ETF's only and charges 0.15%/yr in fess. They allow the user to manage their portfolio only by changing the investment mix (stocks/bonds).  My mix over the last 2.5 yrs has averaged at 40% stocks and 60% bonds.  As of today my returns have been

Earnings over the 2.5 yr period:  6.5%   or ~3%/yr !!
Time weighted:                    7.2%

I'm thinking this is pretty low even though my mix is high in bonds.  I'm 58 and working part time and I'm trying to protect my portfolio hence my 40/60 mix.  For sake of argument let's say my current portfolio is worth $100,000.

In order to get better returns I'm thinking of switching to Fidelity and have them manage this IRA portfolio instead of Betterment. I'm not very knowledgable or interested in money management.

I realize that Fidelity will charge much more for the service than the very low Betterment fees of 0.15% /yr.  But if they can bring me returns closer to 6-7%/yr then it's worth it correct?

To that end is there a calculator tool available online that allows me to compare my returns to the average/typical returns over the past 2.5 yrs for a 40/60 mix portfolio?  Or is there a way to do it myself?

Answer (score 4):

Nobody can give you a safe 6% return with that portfolio under current conditions. It looks like the current 10 year treasury is yielding about 2.2%. With 60% in bonds, the stocks would have to yield about 12%, which just isn't happening safely now.

Comment: Would you consider my current portfolio return of 3.5%/yr over the past 2.5 yrs normal?

Comment: Well the S&P two year return is about 5.36%. So, 40% that and 60% 2.2% is 3.46%, so you got somewhat better than would be expected for that asset allocation.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this advice is late, but for others who may see it...

It may be worth while to investigate Warren Buffet's advice. "Invest in Index EFT's". He had a 10 year bet ($500k wager) against 5 managed funds to beat the VOO index and they could not come close. Index EFT's average 10% per year, but you have to be prepared to ride out market fluctuations with how close you are to retirement (have ~ 3 yrs in living expenses easily available and not subject to market conditions).